# Imprimir Hola Mundo usando KPL en java

Tags: java

Intento mandar un Hola Mundo a un impresora termica Zebra modelo [KR203](https://www.zebra.com/la/es/products/printers/kiosk/kr200-series.html), estas impresoras usan el lenguaje [KPL](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/kr203-pm-en.pdf) (Kiosko Printer Language), al imprimir una página de prueba sale de manera correcta pero con mi código se queda en: "Imprimiendo...".

Este es mi codigo:

```
public void Imprimir() {
    PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    System.out.println("Default" + printService);
    String zplCommand = "^XA\n"
            + "^FO10,0^ARN,11,7^FD SOME TEXT ^FS\n"
            + "^FO300,0^ARN,11,7^FD SOME VALUE ^FS\n"
            + "^FO10,35^ARN,11,7^FD SOME TEXT ^FS\n"
            + "^FO300,35^ARN,11,7^FD SOME VALUE ^FS\n"
            + "^FO10,70^ARN,11,7^FD SOME CODE ^FS\n"
            + "^FO10,115^ARN,11,7^BCN,60,Y,Y,N^FD 23749237439827 ^FS\n"
            + "^XZ";
    byte[] by = zplCommand.getBytes();
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(by, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();
    try {
        job.print(doc, null);  
        //job.print(doc, attributeSet);
    } catch (PrintException e) {
        System.out.println("e " + e);
    }
}
```

Nota: Es una aplicación de escritorio

Comment: El desarrollo que estas haciendo es en escritorio? es decir no es en una aplicación Android?

Comment: Es en escritorio...

Comment: Ah ok, yo tengo alguna experiencia con impresoras Zebra portatiles para conectarlas por bluetooth con dispositivos móviles en Android. Pero de escritorio la verdad no tengo mucho conocimiento. Tal vez si buscas en el [developer center](https://developer.zebra.com/welcome) de zebra por modelo de impresora, encuentres el sdk que te ayude a hacer impresiones sin tener que irte al nivel de escribir en KPL, incluso revisa la documentación.

Comment: Estuve revisando el sdk link-os pero no tiene soporte para este tipo de impresoras

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar mi problema crei que era necesario usar los comandos kpl para imprimir más tarde por intento y error pude imprimir usando estas líneas:

```
public void PrintTicketZ() {        
    PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    attributeSet.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
    attributeSet.add(new Copies(1));
    attributeSet.add(new JobName("PrintService", null));
    attributeSet.add(new MediaPrintableArea(10, 0, 60, 400, MediaPrintableArea.MM));

    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.setPrintable(new Printable() {
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
            if (pageIndex == 0) {
                int h = 100;
                int w = 100;
                String company="--";                      
                try {
                    double x = pf.getImageableX();
                    double y = pf.getImageableY();
                    Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
                    pf.getPaper().setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    g2d.translate(x, y);
                    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                    g2d.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 10));
                    g2d.drawString("FOLIO: ", 105, 40);
                    g2d.drawString("FECHA: ", 0, 60);
                    g2d.drawString("HORA: ", 0, 75);
                    g2d.drawString("N° EMPLEADO: " , 0, 100);
                    g2d.drawString("EMPRESA: " , 0, 115);
                    g2d.drawString("EMPLEADO: ", 0, 130);   
                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error " + e);
                }
                return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
            } else {
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
        }
    });

    PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    if (defaultPrintService != null) {
        try{
            String print_default = defaultPrintService.getName();
            pj.setPrintService(defaultPrintService);
            pj.print(attributeSet);
            log.info("Printing...");

            PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = defaultPrintService.getAttributes();
            String trabajo = printServiceAttributeSet.get(QueuedJobCount.class).toString();
            int trabajos = Integer.parseInt(trabajo);

        } catch (PrinterException pe) {
            log.error("Error al imprimir: " + pe);
            System.out.println(pe);
        }
    }
}
```